# Weird display using LinearLayout

Tags: android, drawable, android-drawable

I decided to tryout android and I wanted to create a simple layout but the rendering is not quite what I expected. what could be wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/post_background">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="80"
            android:id="@+id/comment_box"
            android:background="@drawable/post_inner"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="comment goes here" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:id="@+id/send"
            android:background="@drawable/post_inner"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="SEND"  />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

the rendering looks like this [image]

the TextView is not well alligned horizontally with the EditText.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the height of the `TextView` to

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why, but if you replace your "send" attribute `android:layout_margin` with `android:padding` it works :)

Comment: yeah, but that's not quite what i wanted. I can build on it nut i'm still curious why this isn't working

Comment: maybe the implementation of margin on TextView is different than on the EditText. Android has some quite strange bugs :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this solution, which pretty much should be the same (without the wrapping `LinearLayout` that is):

```
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/post_background">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/send"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/post_inner"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:text="SEND"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    />

  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/comment_box"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/post_inner"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:text="comment goes here"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/send"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```